# Rubik cube theory and commutative matrices

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, symmetric-groups, rubiks-cube

I was reading the [same paper](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/300228/rubik-cube-finite-non-abelian-group) on solving the Rubik cube. The 20 pages or so are mostly proofs and introduction to group theory which preface an algorithm for solving near the end. On pages 13-14 they introduce the *commutator* $PMP^{-1}M^{-1}$, then *conjugation* of $M$ by $P$, $PMP^{-1}$, then prove that conjugacy is an equivalence relation. $(PMP^{-1})M^{-1}$ looks so close to $PMP^{-1}$, and also to the Jordan decomposition of matrices $A = PJP^{-1}$, but they do not appear to discuss whether any of that is meaningful. The significance of the commutator and conjugacy as an equivalence relation also does not seem to be developed any further when they finally present the algorithm toward the end.

Is there some connection here between the conjugacy equivalence relation, the commutator, complete commutivity on a group, and the Jordan decomposition of matrices? Is conjugacy somehow useful to identify commutative groups, for example, a subset of matrices which form an abelian group?

Comment: Regarding your last question: If $AB=BA$ for all $A,B$ in a group, what is $A^{-1}BA$?  What about $A^{-1}B^{-1}AB$?

Comment: I think I understand what you mean. For all similar matrices $A, B$ of the same group, if their commutator is the identity, then the operation is commutative and the group is abelian. Is it generally easier to show that the commutator is the identity than show $AB = BA$?

Comment: The commutator describes exactly *how* two elements do not commute in the sense that $AB=BA[A,B]$ (where $[A,B]$ denotes $A^{-1}B^{-1}AB$, a common notation).  One reason it is preferred in theory contexts is that by defining $G^\prime=\langle [A,B]:A,B\in G\rangle$, we can define the *abelianization* of a group $G/G^{\prime}$, which is exactly the biggest abelian quotient one can make out of $G$ (in the sense that $G/N$ is abelian $\Leftrightarrow G^\prime\leqslant N$).

Comment: Conjugation is preferred for many reasons, however, especially in the contest of *group actions*.  It turns out that by letting a group act on itself$^\star$ or its set of subgroups by conjugation, one can deduce a great deal of information about its structure.  ($^\star$ this basically means conjugating every group element by each $g\in G$, then looking at which parts of $G$ become separated.  this is usually covered around week 8 or so of a group theory course.)

Comment: @Alexander if I follow what you said, $AB=BA[A,B]$ if and only if elements of the group $G$ commute. Also, that $G/G' = AB(A^{-1}B^{-1}AB) ^{-1}= AB(ABA^{-1}B^{-1})$. I do not know what the significance of that is; I plan to read First Course in Group Theory by Fraleigh. I think what I am trying to ask is, whether the resemblance between the commutator and the conjugation is more than coincidental. As in, is conjugation necessary to define the commutator? Can one exist independent of the other?

Comment: $AB=BA[A,B]$ all the time: $BA(A^{-1}B^{-1}AB)=B(AA^{-1})B^{-1}AB=(BB^{-1})AB=AB$.  So $[A,B]=1$ if and only if $AB=BA$, i.e. if and only if $A$ commutes with $B$.  Thus a group $G$ is abelian if and only if $[A,B]=1$ for all $A,B\in G$.  $G/G^\prime$ is a quotient group: you'll learn about what these are when you read Fraleigh, after which what I've said about $G^\prime$ will make more sense.  Conjugation isn't necessary to define the commutator.  They are related (it's more than coicidental), but they're often used for different things.

Answer (score -2):

(This answer only discusses under the context of the MIT paper OP referred to.)

I have done a research on "why the heck did they put commutator and conjugation in Rubik's Cube notes" (written in a more polite language of course) and read tons of materials related to Rubik's Cube.

Basically, there is no theoretical significance now. It is useful for practical reason and stays there for historic and educational reasons.

For people who has attempted solving the Cube, I'm sure it happens at some point of time that you say to yourself "let's put this cubie away using move $A$ so the next move $B$ (which usually does something helpful) does not affect it, and we can bring it back later with a reverse move $A^{-1}$". This is conjugation $ABA^{-1}$. Commutator has similar practical meaning.

They are useful when people want to figure out by themselves how to solve the Cube because they are simple and the effect is obvious to eyes, so they are used extensively in last century when people do not have the computational power to look at the mathematical essence of the Cube. I believe Singmaster's *Notes on Rubik's Magic Cube* and possibly one issue of Hofstadter's *Metamagical Themas* that introduces Rubik's Cube have significant influence on this.

Right now the academia is not really concerned about how to solve the Cube anymore since you can easily find some algorithms online. Rubik's Cube is mostly used for demonstrating or introducing concepts in group theory, and given that historically people often see commutator and conjugation in books about Rubik's Cube, it is natural to pick them as two of the concepts that are demonstrated by Rubik's Cube.

Comment: In fact there is enormous theoretical significance of commutator and conjugation in group theory, and it is not simply a historical coincidence that they are useful in the solution to Rubik's cube.